# ReadTheDocs: docs not being built on pull request

Tags: read-the-docs

I have a single Python project on GitHub which has a User, Developer and Reference Guide ('psyclone', 'psyclone-dev' and 'psyclone-ref', respectively). Each of these has its own RTD project (configured to use the appropriate conf.py for each document). This all works fine for the standard 'latest' and 'stable' versions.

I now want to have RTD build the documentation for Pull Requests and have used the 'Advanced Settings' page and checked the box marked 'Build pull requests for this project'. Now, when I push to an existing PR, I see that a new build is generated for the User Guide, as I would expect.

However, neither the Developer or Reference Guides have new builds triggered, despite me performing the same configuration for all three. Is there something obvious that I may be missing?

Many thanks for any pointers,

Andy.

Comment: You need to have a one-to-one correspondence of RTD "project" to set of docs. You must break apart your docs into three separate repos or projects, or merge the docs into a single set of docs with a single `conf.py`.

Comment: I have three separate documents with three separate `conf.py` files, e.g. `docs/user_guide/conf.py`, `docs/dev_guide/conf.py` etc. To clarify, when you say "you must break apart your docs into three separate repos or projects" are you saying the building of PRs only works in that case? If that's the case the RTD documentation needs updating.

Comment: No, you want to make RTD do something it was never designed to do. There is a one-to-one-to-one-to-one correspondence between a RTD project, a set of documentation, a `conf.py`, and a project repository. You need to either combine all your docs into a single set or break them apart into separate repos.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I guess I won't be using the PR build functionality then :-)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem. Do you have 3 repositories _and_ 3 Read the Docs projects? If that's the case, you have to enable the PR on all of them to work. If it's working when pushing on some repositories but not on all of them, you may want to check the troubleshooting guide at https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pull-requests.html#troubleshooting